# How to retrieve file names from S3 bucket and all of the subfolders

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to retrieve all file names from my s3 bucket. But I don't need everything, only the file names that are in certain locations in the bucket. Having difficulties doing so. I'm trying to use Boto3.Resource but not much luck. I'm able to connect to the bucket and retrieve all the names of the buckets. But when it comes to subfolders, getting issues.

Here is my code:

```
 import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource(
     service_name = 's3',
     region_name = 'us-west-1',
     aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     aws_secret_access_key = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY')

 for x in s3.buckets.all():
    print(x)
 # I am able to list the names of the buckets.

 # loop through all buckets
 for x in s3.buckets.all():
     # make sure this is my bucket.
     if x == 'my-data-bucket':
       objs = list(x.objects.filter(Delimiter = '', Prefix='my-data-bucket/helpdesk/production/docs/'))
         for i in range(0, len(objs)):
             print(objs[i].key)
             # print all the file names.
```

Please keep in mind the "docs" subfolder has additional sub folders like 001, 002, 003 ... etc and each folder has also documents

The goal is to list all file names in a csv file similar to this format

```
      /my-data-bucket
         /helpdesk/production/docs/001/x.pdf
         /helpdesk/production/docs/001/zz.pdf
         /helpdesk/production/docs/002/aa.pdf
         /helpdesk/production/docs/003/rr.pdf
          etc .....
```

Comment: You cannot filter it more using the list objects API. Why don't you just get list of all the objects in the prefix you want and then filter them in python?

Comment: meaning:  objs = list(s3.Bucket(my-data-bucket).objects.all())  -- add everything to a list just like so, but how would you filter them at this point? thanks

Comment: You can use the listobjectsv2 client call(https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) to get all the objects and specify prefix. This will return a list of all the objects. Now iterate through this list and add items you need to a new filtered list.

Comment: How many objects are in the bucket? How often do you need this listing? I'm asking because it might be easier to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

Comment: Objects in a bucket is more than a 1000 and it will keep growing. How often ... daily...

Comment: listobjectsv2 has a limit of 1000, but is this limit for the whole bucket or each subfolder??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solve this is, I was able to put all objects in a list like so:

```
all_objects = list(s3.Bucket('Bucket_Name').objects.all())

looped through all objects:
     for x in all_objects:
        # appended all objects to different list

create a dictionary of lists like dict = {'x': list1, 'y': list2, ....}
created a dataframe (df = pd.DataFrame(dict))
```